# User not creating in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this very weird issue that I cant really get why it's not working.

This is the test that I'm running to test post comments

https://gist.github.com/2794100

now I added 2 extra tests there to get an idea as to why it wasnt working the "user should exist" and "post should exist" to try and understand what's going on, all I gathered is that the user is not creating.
Which is weird cause when I run this other test everything works fine

https://gist.github.com/2794105

the user creation is a copy and paste, seeing as I have the email as a unique key I even tried running the test by itself without any other tests to make sure there was no conflict and I also tried running it with a fresh made database.

if I run each command on the rails console everything works, it's just on the test itself that it doesnt work

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What is rpsec giving as the failure reason? Are you using database cleaner to reset your database between tests? Did you run `rake db:test:prepare` after migrating your development database to get the new columns into the test DB?

Comment: @DVG I added the errors on this gist https://gist.github.com/2794100 thanks and yes I did rake db:test:prepare and I also deleted the db all together and made new ones, still no help, I also got rid of the unique index and it did nothing

Comment: All your failures are because your object is not passing the validators you've set up in your model. You might want to look there if jdoe's answer hasn't gotten you out of trouble already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is full of lines like:

```
before { @post.title == "Example Post"}
```

It's just a comparison, not an assignment. This doesn't make any sense!

You always refer to implicit subject (`it { should ...`), which in your case is a new instance of PostComment. You should specify what exactly are you testing, like:

```
subject { @foo }
```

Or just explicitly name it:

```
it 'should be valid even if something is nil' do
  before { @foo.name = nil }
  @foo.should be_valid
end
```

Comment: I want the test to compare not to assign, I wanna make sure that the relations work, so that I can check the user's post title for example, or any other parts, like the reply to a comment or a post, I create the objects first and then I make sure they work the way I expect them to

Comment: `@post.title == "Example Post"` -- this isn't test. Do you see any `should` there? It's just a statement that is executed and its result is dropped as you don't assign it anywhere. The test is `@post.title.should == "Example Post"`, but it isn't appropriate to put it in the `before` block.

Comment: thanks @jdoe I get it a bit more now, just started with rails, if I were to test the comparison that way, what would be the bedt way to do it? Thanks

Comment: I already told you: `@post.title.should == "Example Post"`. Put it in `it 'should have title Example Post' do ... end`